# How can I get C++ wfstream to work with Unicode filepath?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, filereader, wifstream

I have an application that is working with file I/O using utf-8 encoded widestrings.

Working Code:

```
const wchar_t* wc = L"C:\Documents\TestPath\TestFile.txt";
std::wfstream wf(wc);
wf.imbue(std::locale(wf.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>()));
return wf.is_open();
...
wf << L"測試文件夾" << L"\n";
```

However, once unicode characters are introduced in the filepath the file no longer opens properly. Ie. the following code does not work and returns false:

```
const wchar_t* wc = L"C:\Documents\測試文件夾\TestFile.txt";
std::wfstream wf(wc);
return wf.is_open();
```

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like there should be a simple way to get wfstream working with unicode filepaths but I have searched all over the internet and cannot find one.

Thanks

Comment: Do you not get any warnings from the compiler? Even with no warning options specified, MSVC [gives me some](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x9oE9v).

Comment: There are no warnings from the compiler. When I follow the stack to see where the open is failing, it seems to be at line 234 in <fstream> where ```if (_Myfile != 0 || (_File = _Fiopen(_Filename, _Mode, _Prot)) == 0)``` produces a failbit.

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code as it works fine with ASCII filepaths and unicode file content.

Comment: `L"...` is not a UTF-8 encoded literal. Your source file might be UTF-8 encoded. Are you using `/utf-8` compiler switch?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help everyone.

I found out how to get the code working with an unusual solution, which might help anyone else in the same situation:

1. use C-style _wfopen to create file

```
FILE * fp = _wfopen(cpFullPath, L"w"); 
fclose(fp);
```

2. use ::GetShortPathW function to get short ASCII representation of UTF8 path to newly created file

```
wchar_t short_path[511] {} ;                                                
::GetShortPathNameW( cpFullPath, short_path, 511 ) ;
// cpFullPath is L"C:\\Desktop\\測試文件夾\\те \x81това \x8f папка\\file.txt" 
// short_path becomes L"C:\\Desktop\\12BE~3\\81C2~6\\file.txt"
```

3. open file using wfstream and imbue stream for UTF8 I/O

```
std::wfstream textFileStream;
textFileStream.open(short_path, ios::in | ios::out);
textFileStream.imbue(std::locale(textFileStream.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string literals need to escape `\` characters, eg:

```cpp
const wchar_t* wc = L"C:\\Documents\\TestPath\\TestFile.txt";
```

```cpp
const wchar_t* wc = L"C:\\Documents\\測試文件夾\\TestFile.txt";
```

Otherwise, use raw string literals instead:

```cpp
const wchar_t* wc = LR"(C:\Documents\TestPath\TestFile.txt)";
```

```cpp
const wchar_t* wc = LR"(C:\Documents\測試文件夾\TestFile.txt)";
```

That being said, double check that the charset used to save your cpp file matches the charset the compiler uses to parse the file, otherwise non-ASCII characters like `測試文件夾` won't work in string literals correctly.

Otherwise, use Unicode escape sequences instead:

```cpp
const wchar_t* wc = L"C:\\Documents\\\u6e2c\u8a66\u6587\u4ef6\u593e\\TestFile.txt";
```